# How to use like operator in sql to find some word in a text on another text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to use like operator in sql query to check a text words in another text on database records to find any records like this text words
for example:

```
my text is : ajax,net,apache,sql

and records like : 

assembly,c#,java,apache
ajax,pascal,c,c++
...
```

I need a query to find any rows has my text words

this picture is search input

[image]

and I'll find any rows has words in my search string

[image]

```
        SELECT
        dbo.tblProjects.id, dbo.tblProjects.prTitle, dbo.tblUsers.id AS UserID,tblUsers.nickname, 
        dbo.tblProjects.prTags, dbo.tblProjects.prDesc, dbo.tblProjects.prFaDate
    FROM
        dbo.tblUsers 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.tblProjects ON dbo.tblUsers.id = dbo.tblProjects.UserID

    where (tblUsers.id=@userid)and(dbo.tblProjects.tags like @userskills + '%')

    order by dbo.tblProjects.id desc
```

Sami Update

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Dashboard_My_Skills_Projects]
(
  @userid bigint,
  @userskills nvarchar(100)
)
as
begin
    SELECT T.id, 
           T.prTitle, 
           U.id AS [UserID],
           U.nickname,
           T.prTags, 
           T.prDesc, 
           T.prFaDate

    FROM dbo.tblUsers U INNER JOIN dbo.tblProjects T ON U.id = T.UserID
    WHERE U.id = @userid
          AND
          T.tags IN(
                     SELECT tags
                     FROM dbo.tblProjects T1 CROSS JOIN 
                                  (
                                    SELECT Value 
                                    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@userskills, ',')
                                  ) TT
                     WHERE T1.tags LIKE '%' + Value + '%'
                   )


    order by T.id desc


end
```

tblUsers

[image]

tblProjects

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Those words you want to check, are they stored on the database also or are they fixed? You want to return the records that contain any or all of those words? This record example `assembly,c#,java,apache` is just one record or each word separated by comma is a record?

Comment: Please also specify (and tag the question) with the sql database platform you are using (eg. sql-server, oracle, mysql, etc)

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm using sql server

Comment: You first need to comma-separate the string and then perform use LIKE with each one of them.

Comment: you'll require a dynamic `where`  which you can append with select query after applying string split function

Comment: SQL Server has types **designed** for holding multiple values. The most obvious one of these is a *table* with multiple rows. Which is how these tags *should* be being stored. Rather than forcing them into a comma separated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY`, `STRING_SPLIT()` and `LIKE` as

```
  CREATE TABLE T(
  Tags VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Analytics,Amazon Web Service,Active Directory'),
('BMC Remedy,Big Data,Ajax'),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache'),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache'),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache'),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache'),
('Apple Safari,Analytics,Ajax');

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(45) = 'Active Directory,Ajax,Azure';

SELECT DISTINCT Tags
FROM T CROSS APPLY (SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Search, ',')) TT
WHERE Tags LIKE '%' + Value + '%';
```

**Returns:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                      Tags                       |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Analytics, Amazon Web Service, Active Directory |
| Apple Safari, Analytics, Ajax                   |
| Azure, Assembly, Appache                        |
| BMC Remedy, Big Data, Ajax                      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fab8e756b17d4e88e99ce668134e19e3)**

**Note:** **[`STRING_SPLIT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function is avaliable only on 2016+ versions, so you need to create your own if you are not working on 2016+ versions.

---

*UPDATE*

```
CREATE TABLE Tags(
  Tags VARCHAR(100),
  UserID INT
);

CREATE TABLE Users(
  UserID INT,
  UserName VARCHAR(45)
 );

INSERT INTO Tags VALUES
('Analytics,Amazon Web Service,Active Directory', 1),
('BMC Remedy,Big Data,Ajax', 2),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache', 3),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache', 1),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache', 4),
('Azure,Assembly,Appache', 2),
('Apple Safari,Analytics,Ajax', 1);

INSERT INTO Users VALUES
(1, 'User1'),
(2, 'User2'),
(3, 'User3'),
(4, 'User4');

DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(45) = 'Active Directory,Azure',
        @UserID INT = 1;

SELECT U.UserID,
       U.UserName,
       T.Tags Skills
FROM Users U INNER JOIN Tags T ON U.UserID = T.UserID
WHERE U.UserID = @UserID
      AND
      T.Tags IN(
                 SELECT Tags
                 FROM Tags T1 CROSS JOIN 
                              (
                                SELECT Value 
                                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Search, ',')
                              ) TT
                 WHERE T1.Tags LIKE '%' + Value + '%'
               )
```

**[Here is a live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7768e109389dd941fa79c431963408f)**

and **[here is your stored procedure works just fine and as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cbef3d8d5e4b6761eb61f2e15748c8e3)**

Comment: Ty but search input it can be variable but you used fixed input string

Comment: @ZahraNaeimpour Eh? are you sure? Can't you see `@Search` there? change the value or length as you like.

Comment: ty but how i can change it with my select query? i added my select query on this post

Comment: ty i updated my select query like your query but now it show all user record and search parameter does not take a effect plz check my update query in post

Comment: @ZahraNaeimpour No, it returns the `User1` and rows from `Tags` table where this user has `Active Directory` or `Azure`

Comment: look i add 2 picture in my post one is tblUsers and second is tblProjects i need when a user logged in it show that projects from tblProjects in picture 2 than user skills is in project tags but with your query it show all projects if skills is in tags or not

Comment: and it must show 1 record from project table that it have BMC Remedy tag

Comment: you can remove userid condition

Comment: @ZahraNaeimpour Checkout the last updates, your procedure work just fine and as expected.

Comment: ty but can you modify and update your select query with my tables name? (tblUsers , tblProjects) and remove userid condition

Comment: ty alot i modified query

Comment: sami now i have one problem again look when my search parameter is "BMC Remedy,ajax" it show me duplicate records

Comment: in your query example is same problem "here is your stored procedure works just fine and as expected"

Comment: @ZahraNaeimpour Check this one https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd29df141806c0af6d11fb59afef9610

Comment: ty sami you helped me too much and i have one more problem "The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable." i have two fields they are ntext datatype and i dont want to change to another type but i can change datatype in select query, is it possible?

Comment: ty i used CAST to change datatype in select query

Answer (score 0):

`Like` are to search for a specified pattern in a column..

And as @Pedro state in comment.. I hope you are not make this in just 1 record..

You can use

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE your_text LIKE '%ac%';
```

You can read more about `Like` operator in [*Here*](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

*EDIT* :

You can use `String_Split` function

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   table
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT 
              *  
           FROM 
              STRING_SPLIT(Tags, ',')  
           WHERE 
              value IN ('Active Directory', 'Ajax', 'Azure')
```

Comment: it is not work your query find any value start with that string but i need find any word is like my string words

Comment: My bad.. Now check @ZahraNaeimpour.. :)

Comment: *Not work* are not good statement.. Tell what you are really facing.. And why it is not work..

Comment: look my post again i add 2 pictures

Comment: Ty but search input it can be variable but you used fixed input string

Answer (score 0):

### First Create Function

```
Create FUNCTION fn_SplitADelimitedList
(
   @String NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
   RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE(
   Value nvarchar(500)
   )
As
 BEGIN
      DECLARE @SplitLength INT
      DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(10) 
      SET @Delimiter = ','

      WHILE len(@String) > 0
      BEGIN
           SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE charindex(@Delimiter, @String)
           WHEN 0 THEN
           datalength(@String) / 2
           ELSE
           charindex(@Delimiter, @String) - 1
           END)

       INSERT INTO @SplittedValues
            SELECT cast(substring(@String, 1, @SplitLength) AS nvarchar(50))
            WHERE
            ltrim(rtrim(isnull(substring(@String, 1, @SplitLength), ''))) <> '';
            SELECT @String = (CASE ((datalength(@String) / 2) - @SplitLength)
            WHEN 0 THEN
            ELSE
            right(@String, (datalength(@String) / 2) - @SplitLength - 1)
            END)
      END
 RETURN
END
```

### Then Query Like this

```
DECLARE @yourtext NVARCHAR(400) = 'Apple, Active Directory'
SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Value)),
em.tags
FROM tblTest em
CROSS APPLY fn_SplitADelimitedList(em.tags) c
inner join 
(SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') DATA
FROM
(
SELECT CAST('<X>'+REPLACE(@yourtext, ',', '</X><X>')+'</X>' AS XML) AS String
) AS A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/X') AS Split(a)) v 
on LTRIM(RTRIM(c.Value)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(v.DATA))
```

Comment: Ty but search input it can be variable but you used fixed input string

Comment: no problem, just pass your variable value @ZahraNaeimpour